# How do you create a drop-down editor in the Angular 2 Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Using the Angular 2 Kendo Grid, I currently can specify an editor for text, numeric, and boolean.  How do I create a custom editor or more specifically a drop-down list editor?

Answer (score 7):

You can define templates in grid columns, where you can put whatever you want, including dropdowns:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <kendo-dropdownlist [(ngModel)]="dataItem.itemId" [data]="listItems"></kendo-dropdownlist>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-template-forms/

Comment: Thanks.  I should have specified I was using their reactive forms.  But this will probably do the trick for me.

Comment: @JamesBender This answer dates from an early version of Angular and a beta version of Kendo. <template> tags must now be replaced by <ng-template> in newer versions of Angular. Maybe it was your issue... I'll update the answer accordingly.